# Pulling values from a sepcific row in table

Tags: database, query, wpdb

I'm trying to get the first and last name values for ONE person in a database where the meet certain conditions of being a team leader and having a specific project id. Because of this, it will always be one row.

I have this

```
$leader_result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT user_first_name, user_last_name FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."mro_attendees WHERE event_id = ".$project_id." AND user_role = 'team_leader' LIMIT 1");
```

But I'm not sure how to get the first and last names from they query. I tried setting up a while but when I did a test and echo'd the variables for the whiles I got nothing. What exactly am I doing wrong here? Is there something wrong with the WP query itself?

Tried with updates and still not getting information out of the echo.

```
$leader_result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT user_first_name, user_last_name FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."mro_attendees WHERE event_id = ".$project_id." AND user_role = 'team_leader' LIMIT 0,1");
$leader_select = mysql_query($leader_result);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($leader_select);
$leader_first = $row[0];
```

If I echo $leader_first I get nothing as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
$leader_result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT user_first_name, user_last_name FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."mro_attendees WHERE event_id = ".$project_id." AND user_role = 'team_leader' LIMIT 0,1")
```

`foreach($leader_result as $row=>$value)
{
    echo $value->column_name;
}`

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: there is something wrong in the query , in the limit section , limit is being set as 1 , whereas the limit takes 2 arguments , offset and limit, so setting `limit 0,1` will fetch 1 row from the table .

Comment: So if I use `mysql_query` on on that result and fetch the row I should be able to get the results from `$row[0];` and `$row[1];`?

Comment: Seems like that didn't do anything either.

Comment: why do you will use mysql_query in wordpress , there is a function `$results=$wpdb->getresults();` which will give u object  having all the results.

Comment: if it is correct answer , please mark it as correct.